# Getting attributes of polygons that line overlaps using Leaflet and Turf

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, geometry, turf

I have a Leaflet Polyline:

```
var polyline = L.Polyline(polylineData).addTo(map);
```

and a Leaflet GeoJSON of Polygons:

```
var countries = L.geoJson(countries, {style:{color:'darkgrey', opacity:1,fillColor:'lightgrey', fillOpacity:0.7, weight:2}}).addTo(map);
```

They look like this on the map:

[image]

Imagine that the Polyline represents a driving route that goes across Europe. The GeoJSON is a collection of National Boundaries with associated attribute information. **I need to know what countries the driving route goes through**. For example, In the case of this line I need to know that it is passing through the United Kingdom, France and Switzerland. The GeoJSON contains the associated country names as properties in each feature.

I am hoping that a function within the Turf.js library is suitable though am not sure which one?

Comment: Have added code excerpts and image to illustrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `countries.eachLayer` group layer method to iterate through layer features and then use `turf.booleanIntersects` method to check which country feature intersects polyline.

To log intersected countries on the console, code could then look something like this (assuming feature property `name` contains country name):

```
var polyline = L.Polyline(polylineData).addTo(map);
var polylineFeature = polyLine.toGeoJSON();

countries.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  if (turf.booleanIntersects(layer.feature, polylineFeature)) {
    console.log(layer.feature.properties.name);
  }
});
```

Comment: Amazing - worked perfect. Thank you so much!